# Copying a table in SQL Server database to Oracle database

Tags: sql-server, oracle, table

I am new to database management. I need to copy a particular table "Attendance" in SQL Server database to Oracle database. There is no connection between the two databases. Also, "Attendance" is updated in real-time in the original SQL database.

I have two options:

1. To pull the data from SQL Server -> Store it -> Push to oracle.
2. Connect the two databases so as the updates are synchronised in real-time.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to go about this. I have researched on this since a week but haven't found exactly what needs to be done.

Comment: try http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_database_link_sql_server_oracle.htm

Comment: The data can never be synchronised in real time, there will always be some kind of latency. How big are the tables, how often are they changed, what is the volume of changes. Is it mainly inserts, updates or a mix of both? You first need to decide on a TRUNCATE/INSERT approach or a CDC (change data capture). You need to  decide on a tool to transfer the data. If you are a beginner at this I suggest MS tools, not oracle ones. One MS tool to transfer data like this is `SSIS, though this is not necessarily the best option for real time replication, and is not the only option.

Comment: oh ,and exactly which version of SQL Server and Oracle?

Comment: @ElectricLlama The table has 4 columns, and the records are in thousands or more. Its just one table. The tables have the employee in and out details. It updates only, hence the number of records is constant. Some kind of latency should be alright, i guess. SQL server 2012 and oracle 11g.

Comment: If there is unlikely to be more than thousands of record then a TRUNCATE/INSERT solution should be fine rather than a more complicated CDC one. Do you want to 'push' the data from SQL Server or pull the data from Oracle? If you want to push from SQL Server you need to install the Oracle driver on the SQL Server.

Comment: @ElectricLlama Either will do. But preferrably the one which is faster and more efficient. What would you suggest? I dont think the records are more than a thousand.

Comment: For a thousand records there will be no performance issues no matter how you do it. The real challenge in your case is making something reliable that you can maintain yourself. Why don't you follow through the answer proposed below and ask any specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

this can be done if you are using SQL Server Management Studio. The method is as follows:-

Goto the source schema on SQL Server

Right click > Export data

Select source as current schema

Select destination as "Oracle OLE provider"

Select properties, then add the service name into the first box, then username and 
password, be sure to click "remember password"

Enter query to get desired results to be migrated

Enter table name, then click the "Edit" button

Alter mappings, change nvarchars to varchar2, and INTEGER to NUMBER

Run

Repeat process for remaining tables, save as jobs if you need to do this again in the future

Comment: I assume the second time this is run duplicate data will be pushed over. Or does this process automatically clear the target table beforehand? You will also need to install the Oracle driver to do this.

Comment: you can choose to either append to the existing table or to truncate the table and then add the data.

Comment: Very handy. What version of SQL Server is that? I can't see the export option in SSMS 2008 R2.

Comment: I am sorry, Right click the schema -> Tasks -> Export

Comment: So, if i follow this solution by @JayNirgudkar and save it as a job, it will perform this transfer of the said data on a regular basis? Also, i need to copy only one particular table. Does this method export the whole database or i can select what to export i.e. table Attendance?

Comment: You can select a single table while it asks you to map the data in the input database and output database, so Single table can be done. But i am not sure if you can save it as a "job". sorry. Do let me know if u can though.

Comment: @JayNirgudkar, thanks for the info! One last question, this process, does it require me to make a connection between these 2 databases in question? If yes, does http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_database_link_sql_server_oracle.htm do the trick? Or something else?

Comment: OK, so you need to be on the server to do this. This will create a SSIS package which you should be able to schedule in a job. You will also need to install the Oracle client on the SQL Server in order to connect to Oracle.

Comment: If i understand your question correctly, the answer would be No. This process does not require a link between 2 databases. Linking 2 means, you can see 1 of the database in the Linked Servers folder within the other database. Hope i am clear.

Comment: The "t_database_link_sql_server_oracle.htm" link you referred to deals with setting up a link _from_ Oracle _to_ SQL Server and is irrelevant for this approach. In this approach you define the connection to Oracle in the destination step.

Comment: @ElectricLlama.. thank you for the answer for job scheduling. and  Pribhat, Hope this was of some help. Cheers.:)